# How to load a particular partition of a Hive table into another Hive table with no partitions?

Tags: hadoop, hive, partition

`HiveTable1` has columns name, email in partition `date=12/12/2014`
There are other date partitions in the table as well.

`HiveTable2` is created with name, email columns.

*How do I transfer the data from HiveTable1 to HiveTable2?*

Answer (score 0):

If you just filter on a single value for the partition key then it will only load that partition.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE HiveTable2
SELECT name, email FROM HiveTable1 WHERE date="12/12/2014";
```